# Powershell Windows user variables appdata

Tags: windows, powershell

The script does not understand the `$dd` variable. How to fix it?

```
$dd = Get-WmiObject Win32_UserProfile -Filter "Special=$false and Loaded=$true" | select -ExpandProperty LocalPath -Last 1 
Copy-Item -force "\\share\*" -Destination $dd\AppData\Roaming -Recurse
```

Comment: What is the value of `$dd`? Please show the output of `echo "-$dd-"`.

Comment: Please be more specific. What do you mean by _does not understand the $dd variable_. Do you get any error messages? What is the result of the `Get-WmiObject` command? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Try using quotes in the destination parameter., e.g. `-Destination "$dd\AppData\Roaming"`

Comment: As `(Get-WmiObject Win32_UserProfile -Filter "Special=$false and Loaded=$true").LocalPath` points also to `$ENV:USERPROFILE` why not simply use `$ENV:APPDATA` for the destination?

Comment: the script is launched when the user logs in via GPO, which means it will be executed on behalf of the system, which means that the file will be sent to a wrong directory

Comment: @GertJanKraaijeveld: While using double quotes never hurts (for string arguments), they make no difference here; e.g., try `$dd = '(# @$'; Write-Output $dd\AppData\Roaming`, and you'll see that the argument is passed just fine.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers, the problem was in quotes :))

Comment: @PokeshG: If the ultimate problem and solution are potentially of interest to future readers, I encourage you to write up the solution in an answer. Otherwise, please consider deleting your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
$dd = Get-WmiObject Win32_UserProfile -Filter "Special=$false and Loaded=$true" |
      select -ExpandProperty LocalPath -Last 1
Copy-Item -Force "\\share*" -Destination "$dd\AppData\Roaming" -Recurse
```